# turning a complex query into cakephp pagination conditions

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp, pagination

I allow my users to select a mile radius number and a location and then I'm attempting to get results back which are within that radius. There's a bunch of tutorials online and there's one which appears to have the perfect query

```
'SELECT id, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM markers HAVING distance < 25 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20;'
```

But I'm using cakephp and I want to use the pagination component so I need to translate that query into a conditions array which selects all markers and associated data. Can anyone help me out? I'm new to cakephp and absolutely useless with sql at the best of times.

The HAVING bit in particular is confusing...

EDIT

I'm now using this code

```
$this->Paginator->settings = array(
            'fields'=>array('id','( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos(radians( '.$lat.' ) ) * cos( radians( '.$lng.' ) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin(radians( '.$lat.' ) ) ) ) AS distance '),
                                'limit' => 20,
                                'conditions'=>array('distance < '.$miles)
        );
$data = $this->Paginator->paginate('Job');
$this->set(compact('data'));
```

And that at least is running the query, but I'm getting an error saying

```
Unknown column 'distance' in 'where clause'
```

Any ideas?

MORE EDIT

the log is showing

```
SELECT `Job`.`id`, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos(radians( 54.59728500000001 ) ) * cos( radians( -5.930119999999988 ) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin(radians( 54.59728500000001 ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM `trainnation`.`jobs` AS `Job` LEFT JOIN `trainnation`.`users` AS `User` ON (`Job`.`user_id` = `User`.`id`) LEFT JOIN `trainnation`.`courses` AS `Course` ON (`Job`.`course_id` = `Course`.`id`) WHERE 1 = 1 GROUP BY distance having distance < 49 LIMIT 20
```

which looks right but it's not pulling anything at all from the DB now. and there should be at least 9 from those options

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$this->paginate = array('fields'=>array('id','( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos(radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin(radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance '),
'limit' => 20,
'group'=>'distance having distance < 25 ')
);
$marker_data = $this->paginate('Marker');
```

Comment: yeah - but I wanted to use the paginate function - this is a good fall back plan but I'd prefer through the pagination component

Comment: hey there, that looks like it should work but is returning all my markers. I'm using cakephp2.3 and you're code looks slightly different to what I had so I'm going to try it a little different

Comment: I used version 2.1.1. Try to limit 10 then what you get result?

Comment: Check out the edit to my qu, I've put the code I'm trying now there. Note that when I checked my sql log after your code there was none of the sin cos etc which is what made me think it mustn't be picking up the new settings, hence trying this way which is from the manual

Comment: apply group instead of conditions check my edited answer

Comment: hi Sadikhasan, I checked the ssql log and that worked and produces a query which you'd think would work but actually doesn't pull anything. Check out my 2nd edit above. In the meantime I gotta go to bed before the sun comes up (6.22am here), if you can think of anything plz let me know, otherwise thanks for your help so far!